# jq filter to strip out the double colons from a string in a json

Tags: json, jq

I have a use case where I need to strip out the double colons to get the list of IP addresses.

Input: (test.json)

```json
{
  "source_name": "ABC::10.0.0.1::XYZ ABC::10.0.0.2::XYZ ABC::10.0.0.3::XYZ"
}
```

Desired output:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

Could anyone help with this? Any inputs appreciated

Comment: `jq -r '.[] | scan("(?:[0-9]{1,2}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,2}")'`: could be also used; using `scan` function in `jq` with mentioning regex there enabling raw output option in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
jq -r '.source_name | match("::(.*?)::"; "g") | .captures[].string'
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot Philippe :) I'm learning to use complex jq lately. really appreciate your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on spaces, then use substitution to remove the string before and after double colons:

```
jq -r '.source_name | split(" ")[] | sub("^.*?::"; "") | sub("::.*"; "")' file.json
```

Comment: Hi, @choroba Thanks for your response. What if our input is like below

`{"source_name": "ABC DEF::10.0.0.1::XYZ ABC DEF::10.0.0.2::XYZ ABC DEF::10.0.0.3::XYZ"}`

And need the same desired output

Comment: You can create a new question to ask a new question. You can link to the old one for context. Moreover, what about trying something on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using `scan`:

```bash
jq -r '.source_name | scan("::(.*?)::")[]'
```

```json
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DNXsLG59jEy)